# JOptionPane not showing any kind of window when running on IDE

Tags: java

My program is not showing any window when running the JavaDocs JOptionPane examples, i don't get any console errors, am i missing something? I've tried doing all the different ways in the code below. I'm using JAVA 12, NetBeans IDE 11.0, windows 10

```
package jpanelloop;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
/**
 *
 * @author Blue
 */
public class JPanelloop {
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    //Tried this way
    JOptionPane f;

    f = new JOptionPane();

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, "Hello World");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello World");

}}
```

Also This way

```
    package jpanelloop;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author Blue
 */
public class JPanelloop {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        //Tried this way
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "alert", "alert", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

    }

}
```

Comment: Putting a JOptionPane *within* a JOptionPane is a bit weird, but the 2nd code *should* work. Are you sure that the option pane isn't really showing up, but is perhaps behind the IDE?

Comment: Yes, tried to minimize other windows, tried to alt+tab, it just doesn't show up

Comment: I'm gonna try on a different IDE

Comment: What are _the JavaDocs JOptionPane examples_ ?

Comment: The second one, but it somehow got solved

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Reboot PC, now it works fine, Go figure...